# "Solving" for a sequence given an (expected) expression for the summation

Tags: summation, asymptotics, closed-form

Consider the "equation"
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{a_n}\sum_{k=1}^n ka_k = \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{n^2}{\log n}\right).\tag{1}\label{eq:conjec}
\end{equation}
Does there exist some monotonically decreasing sequence $\{a_k\}$ of strictly positive real numbers which satisfies \eqref{eq:conjec}?

Of course, I would also be interested in sequences which 'do better' than that, in the sense of e.g. $\mathcal{O}(n^2/\log^2n)$ or even $\mathcal{O}(n/\log n)$, but my intuition tells me that \eqref{eq:conjec} itself cannot be satisfied given my imposed conditions on $\{a_k\}$. I am unsure how to prove this claim, though.

Also, if there *does* exist such a sequence, I am equally lost in how to go about determining what that sequence actually is.

I am looking mostly for hints about how to think about this or potentially fruitful methods/techniques that I am not aware of. I have been looking through tables of various closed form sums and more or less guess-and-checking modifications of them, with no avail.

Comment: $\frac{a_k}{a_n} \geq 1$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$ therefore your sequence is at least as fast as $n^2$

Comment: @clark, Oh wow, I never thought about it like that. Thanks very much!